# What's the name of this particular economics phenomenon (loss and increase of value over many years)?

Tags: definition, value

I have almost no knowledge of economics so I decided to ask you here. Sorry for tags but I didn't have any idea what should I use.

Some things loss its value due to quality and functionality increase. They can even went out from usage as an effect of a major technological evolution. However, over many years such things can get more and more expensive because they have some important historical value hence become a collectible. Examples: old typewriters, cars, sewing machines, Intel 4004 processors etc.

What's the name of this phenomenon (if any)?

Comment: I hazard a guess "Scarity" ?

Comment: I found this discussion may be nice to have a look https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30616/why-do-some-businesses-choose-scarcity-as-their-business-model-instead-of-raisin